# Robotframework - workflow design

Tags: workflow, robotframework

At the moment I'm using [Taskflow](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/TaskFlow) to specify my test workflow. I'm trying to understand if Robotframework can be used for my tests scenario.

For example, my typical test is:

```
- Start traffic on device1
- While traffic is flowing:
  - Collect via SSH realtime traffic data on device2
  - Collect via SSH realtime traffic data on device3
- Stop traffic on a device1
- Get output data from device2 and device3
- Check outputs
```

I did not find any workflow detail for Robotframework. Is it possible to design such a test in RF?

Riccardo

Comment: Yes , it is possible. You might need the libraries which allow you to do such things (or sreate these libraries yourself).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can be used for your scenario.

Robot Framework uses [external libraries](http://robotframework.org/#Libraries) such as [SSHLibrary](https://github.com/robotframework/SSHLibrary)

Here is a [documentation](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html) to said library with description of concepts, keywords you can use and with examples.

A lot of things are generally possible with Robot Framework as you can always expand it's capabilities by writing your own external libraries if the commonly used ones are not matching your needs. 
But it seems that this library might do exactly what you need.

- You can open several connections
- You can start/execute command
- You can log to file or read output
  ...